# UIScrollView contentLayoutGuide and zooming centered

Tags: uiscrollview, zooming, ios11

The problem to be solved here is how to zoom in a UIScrollView while staying centered. If you don't take some sort of precautions, the default is that as we zoom out, the zoomed view slides up to the top left corner of the scroll view, like this:

[image]

So how to prevent this, and keep the zoomed view in the center as we zoom? As you probably know, there are traditional ways of handling this by messing with the scroll view's layout, as described by Josh and Eliza in the brilliant classic [WWDC video 104 from 2010](http://asciiwwdc.com/2010/sessions/104). This can be done by using a delegate or by subclassing UIScrollView, and gives the desired result:

[image]

Now comes WWDC 2017 video 201 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/201/?time=1496), and there's Eliza making a claim that the new (iOS 11) `contentLayoutGuide` solves the problem of zooming while staying centered in a new way: she says to center the content view at the center of the content layout guide.

But she doesn't *demonstrate*. And when I try it for myself, I find it isn't solving the problem. I'm zooming *in* just fine, but when zooming *out*, so that the zoom scale is smaller than 1, the content view moves up to the top left, just as it always has.

Has anyone figured out what this claim in the video actually means? How does iOS 11 make it easier to zoom centered than in the past?

**EDIT** I actually received a sample project from Apple in response to my bug report, which they claimed illustrated how to solve this, *and it didn't!* So I conclude that even Apple doesn't know what they're talking about here.

Comment: I see that I can sort of implement centered zooming by pinning the center of the scalable view to the center of `frameLayoutGuide` instead, but that doesn't solve the problem, because the result is obviously not scrollable.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same issue, and can't find anyone who has gotten this to work.

Comment: @IMcD23 It's not really a problem; there are long-established ways of zooming while staying centered. The issue in my question is the claim in the video that there is some _new_ way to do it, involving the `contentLayoutGuide`; I still have not found any indication to support that claim.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I just give it a second try but it still failed to work as expected.

Comment: I think this falls under trivial, so I didn't edit, but this links to the moment the claim is made https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/201/?time=1496

Comment: Thanks @hidden-username, I did the edit, good idea

Comment: Having same issue.  No examples or proper documentation and only  two lines of code introduced in wwdc to rapturous applause and then no follow up.  Would love to see if anybody has figured out how to do this.

Comment: This still seems to be the issue as of iOS 12, would like to see how it is supposed to work

Comment: @matt could you show us Apple's sample code? I'm interested in how Apple thinks it should work :D.

Comment: Also for all that are forced to go the 2010 way of zooming: [This repo](https://github.com/ssamadgh/PhotoScroller_Completed_Sample_Code_Part_I) contains a UIScrollView subclass that got you covered.

Answer (score -3):

The view goes to the top left because the contentSize of the scroll view is not defined. When using the new Auto Layout guides in iOS 11, it's still necessary to define the contentSize.

**Add the following constraints:**

```
scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)
```

---

This worked for me, when I had a contentView with a fixed width/height and the following additional constraints:

```
//  give the centerView explicit height and width constraints
centerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500),
centerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500),

//  pin the center of the centerView to the center of the scrollView's contentLayoutGuide
centerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
centerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
```

Comment: I tried your code (I had in fact tried it already, but I copied it and pasted it in so there can be no mistake) and it didn't work: we don't stay centered when we zoom out, and we don't scroll coherently either. There must be something going on that you're not telling me. Could you post a demo on GitHub? Thx.

Answer (score -4):

This is the solution you are / everybody is looking for. In my case I want to center a view inside a table view scroll view. So if the table view scrolls the custom view will always be in the center of the scroll view content.

```
// create a view
let v:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect.zero)    // use zero if using constraints
    ibTableView.addSubview(v)
    ibTableView.bringSubview(toFront:v)
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = no
v.backgroundColor = .yellow
v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100).isActive = yes
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100).isActive = yes

// set scrollview guides
ibTableView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ibTableView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = yes
ibTableView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ibTableView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = yes

// anchor view
v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ibTableView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = yes
v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:ibTableView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = yes
```

Comment: No, this is about zooming (in particular, it's about keeping a zoomable view centered while it zooms). You haven't understood the question.

Comment: Why don't you actually try the solution and then just add your zooming? Since nobody understood your question…maybe you should rephrase it.

Comment: Very well, did so.